# Everex Systems EV1250: Perhaps a 286 accelerator? I need its manual

Tags: 80286, identify-this-card

[image: EV1250]

[image: EV1250's 80286]

[image: 8088 Cable]

Recently I got an unknown card named EV1250 that I couldn't find any information on what it was.

I assume it's probably a 286 accelerator.

There are some memory chips on the left side of the card and a 40-pin header on the right side. The header's pinout equals 8088's pinout.

I installed the card to my DTK XT clone to check if my guess was correct, but it didn't work.

Please tell me exactly what this is and how it can work.

(July 25, 2022)

I succeeded in making a cable that fits this card, but there is still no good result.

I think the way to solve this issue is to find its manual.
If you have the manual for EV1250, or if you have found it online, please show it to me.

Comment: Sounds quite right. Is it a basic XT clone, or some improved variant (higher clock rate)? Accelerators like that were quite sensitive when it came to clone machines.

Comment: It has higher clock rate, 10mhz.

Comment: Is there a date on the PCB?

Comment: yes. marked 1986

Comment: @StephenKitt Everex started out as add on card maker, moved to making 286 and 386sx accelerators (ca.1985) before doing whole PC (Step series, ca. 1989). PCs that were only partial compatible, at least regarding extensions like their memory scheme and graphics cards. Also a lot of Modems. Went under against dumb cloning as they tried to advance the PC beyond that.

Comment: @Raffzahn I am quite familiar with Everex ;-). I have one of their 286 upgrade cards (but not this one obviously).

Comment: @user24984 Ignoring the commentary at first, the board's connector looks like the old 8-bit ISA (well, the name ISA came along later.) So I'd assume from everything else that this was a way to add an 80286 to an older 8088 system like the PC or PC/XT. If so, I've no clue how to actually use it, though. Perhaps there is a driver that's loaded high in DOS for it? (Now, reading comments... okay. Still might be right about initial impressions.) I developed something similar using the MIPS R2000 in 1986, but for the PC/AT.

Comment: Wouldn't expect it can work with such a badly mangled socket connector on one end of your ribbon cable.

Comment: When you installed the board in your XT, did you connect it to the CPU socket?

Comment: @Brian H The ZIF socket is attached to protect the 40 pins of the 8088 cable and is detachable. When it is  detached, real 40 pins of the 8088 cable are exposed. All the 40 pins are fine and functional. Of course I tested the 8088 cable with the ZIF socket removed.

Comment: @Stephen Kitt Yes I did. But It wouldn't boot. No POST screen...

Comment: A response card close to some ads in the APRIL 1988 Byte magazine lists a bunch of Everex products one of which is **EV-1250 Turbo card for PC/XT (long card)**.  Internet Archive link : https://archive.org/details/byte-magazine-1988-04/page/n36/mode/1up

Comment: Does the PC/XT clone you're trying to test this board in have a turbo button? If so you might want to toggle it into the 4.77Mhz compatibility mode to have a better chance of this card working with it.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Based on what you said, I tested it, but there is still no POST screen and there is a rattling noise from the power supply.

Comment: Oops, I found that the pinout of the 8088 cable was inverted. This is a very big mistake of mine. I'll get the right cable again and test it. Thank you from the bottom of my heart.

Comment: Some accelerators had you put the original CPU on them and used it during post/early-BIOS before switching to the replacement.

Comment: @Brian As you said, I installed EV1250 and turned on the system with 8088 put on the motherboard. It Starts in 8088 mode, but the EV1250 does not have any effect.

Comment: @Sung The 8088 put in the EV1250 (in the empty socket shown in the pictures) not the motherboard.  Or did you just phrase it oddly?

Comment: @brian My poor English caused a misunderstanding. I put it in the motherboard. The empty socket is for 80287.